Question about magnetic and electric monopoles
Suppose magnetic monopoles existed. If you had two monopoles, electric and magnetic, what test would you apply to distinguish one from the other?

Brilliant question.

if you have a magnetic monopole, you have another one. And they interact with each other in the same way as electrical charges.
an electron is an electric charge to the same extent as a magnetic dipole. It is impossible to decompose an electron in our world. In this respect, there are no magnetic monopoles.


Rub a piece of glass with silk (or a piece of amber with fur). If your monopole is attracted or repelled by the glass (amber), it's an electric monopole.
Bring a monopole near a magnetic compass. If your monopole deflects the compass needle, it's a magnetic monopole.
Create a coil out of conducting wire (copper, for example) and hook up the ends to a voltmeter. Launch your monopole through the coil. If the voltmeter registers a voltage, it was a magnetic monopole.
Using the same coil, launch your monopole near the coil so that the path of the particle and the coil are in the same plane. If the voltmeter registers a voltage, it was an electric monopole.
Run an electric current through the coil of wire. If your monopole feels a force when brought near the coil, it's a magnetic monopole.
Connect an ammeter to a metal plate with one wire and then to ground with a second wire. Make sure the plate is electrically isolated from its surroundings. Move your monopole close to the metal plate and then farther away. If a current is measured by the ammeter, it was an electric monopole.
